# What is the canonical way to make autoconf link in Solaris network libraries?

Tags: solaris, autoconf

On Solaris, when you compile a program that uses sockets, you need to link it with `-lnsl -lsocket`.  Many such programs were originally written for Linux (where no extra libraries are needed), and therefore do not check for these libraries in their configure scripts, even though that is a rather simple addition.  Something like this (untested):

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(gethostbyname, nsl, , AC_MSG_ERROR([gethostbyname not found]))
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(connect, socket, , AC_MSG_ERROR([connect not found]))
```

Is there a canonical way to do this check?  Maybe even included in the autoconf distribution?  You would imagine that there is a rather widespread need for that, but Google wouldn't tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think the closest to *a canonical way to check this* is the [`AX_LIB_SOCKET_NSL` macro](http://www.nongnu.org/autoconf-archive/ax_lib_socket_nsl.html) from the [Autoconf Archive](http://www.nongnu.org/autoconf-archive/):

```
# ===========================================================================
#        http://www.nongnu.org/autoconf-archive/ax_lib_socket_nsl.html
# ===========================================================================
#
# SYNOPSIS
#
#   AX_LIB_SOCKET_NSL
#
# DESCRIPTION
#
#   This macro figures out what libraries are required on this platform to
#   link sockets programs.
#
#   The common cases are not to need any extra libraries, or to need
#   -lsocket and -lnsl. We need to avoid linking with libnsl unless we need
#   it, though, since on some OSes where it isn't necessary it will totally
#   break networking. Unisys also includes gethostbyname() in libsocket but
#   needs libnsl for socket().
#
# LICENSE
#
#   Copyright (c) 2008 Russ Allbery <rra@stanford.edu>
#   Copyright (c) 2008 Stepan Kasal <kasal@ucw.cz>
#   Copyright (c) 2008 Warren Young <warren@etr-usa.com>
#
#   Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification, are
#   permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright notice
#   and this notice are preserved.

AU_ALIAS([LIB_SOCKET_NSL], [AX_LIB_SOCKET_NSL])
AC_DEFUN([AX_LIB_SOCKET_NSL],
[
        AC_SEARCH_LIBS([gethostbyname], [nsl])
        AC_SEARCH_LIBS([socket], [socket], [], [
                AC_CHECK_LIB([socket], [socket], [LIBS="-lsocket -lnsl $LIBS"],
                [], [-lnsl])])
])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.  I wasn't aware of the Autoconf Archive :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember any finished code off the top of my head, but you usually want to check whether you can link a program calling the `gethostbyname()` function without any extra libs first. Only if that fails, you want to try the `nsl` library.

Similar things apply e.g. for the `m` library.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind using `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`: it first tries to find the function without any library, and then with each library in the list, in turn.  (In my code, both lists contain a single library, though.)